# Abandoned memory issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, abandoned-memory

Could you help me out please, my app is almost finished, I'm now in the process of optimizing it so I'm using the Instrument Allocations tools and I have a problem vith a view controller but I can't figure out why memory increases each time I go from the main view to the detailedViewController.

Here is the code part that seems to be the problem :

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Create and push a detail view controller.

    self.entriesDetailedViewController = [[EntriesDetailedViewController alloc]init];

Entry *selectedEntry = (Entry *)[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

self.entriesDetailedViewController.entry = selectedEntry;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.entriesDetailedViewController animated:YES];
[self.entriesDetailedViewController release];
}
```

Here is the code for the detailedViewController.h:

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


  @class Entry;

 @interface EntriesDetailedViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> {

//IBOutlet UIButton *createEntryButton;
IBOutlet UITextField *entryTextField1;
IBOutlet UITextView *entryTextField2;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *textbodyBarButton;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem * catLabel;
IBOutlet UINavigationBar *entryNameToolBar;
IBOutlet UINavigationBar *textBodyToolBar;
IBOutlet UIImageView *reviewCheck;
IBOutlet UIImageView *textBackground;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *reviewButton;
BOOL isChecked;

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;


Entry *entry;

    }


 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *entryTextField1;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *entryTextField2;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *textbodyBarButton;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *catLabel;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *entryNameToolBar;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *textBodyToolBar;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *reviewCheck;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *reviewButton;
 @property BOOL isChecked;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *textBackground;

 @property (nonatomic,retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) Entry *entry;


 - (void)setUpUndoManager;
 - (void)cleanUpUndoManager;
 - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)entryTextField2;
 - (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView  *)entryTextField2;
 - (void)saveContext;



 - (IBAction)dismisskeyboard;
 - (IBAction)dismissKeyboardfromTextView;
 - (IBAction) selectReview;


 @end
```

and this this the detailedViewController.m :

```
  #import "EntriesDetailedViewController.h"
  #import "Entry.h"
  #import "TheLearningMachineAppDelegate.h"


  @implementation EntriesDetailedViewController

  @synthesize entryTextField1,entryTextField2,textbodyBarButton,managedObjectContext,catLabel, entryNameToolBar,textBodyToolBar, reviewCheck,reviewButton,isChecked,textBackground, entry, undoManager;


  #pragma mark -
  #pragma mark View lifecycle


  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

  }

  - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];

  // Configure the title, title bar, and table view.

      self.title = @"Consultation";

    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(save:)]; 
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton; 
[rightButton release];

[self setUpUndoManager];

self.entryTextField1.text = self.entry.entryname;
self.entryTextField2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
self.entryTextField2.text = self.entry.textbody;
self.catLabel.title = self.entry.category;
[self.entryTextField2 setFrame:CGRectMake(24, 56, 273, 140)];

self.textBackground.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alert_background.png"];
[self.textBackground setFrame:CGRectMake(0,46,312,140)];



  //Initializing a kind of checkBox button

if ([self.entry.active boolValue] == YES) {

    self.reviewCheck.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedwhitesquare.png"];

    self.isChecked = YES;
}

else {

    self.reviewCheck.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UncheckedWhiteSquare.png"];

    self.isChecked = NO;

}

  }


  - (IBAction) selectReview {

      if (isChecked==NO){
        self.reviewCheck.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedwhitesquare.png"];
    self.isChecked = YES;
    [self.entry setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"active"];
    [self performSelector: @selector(save:)];

}
else {

    self.reviewCheck.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UncheckedWhiteSquare.png"];

    self.isChecked = NO;
    [self.entry setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"active"];
    [self performSelector: @selector(save:)];

}

  }



  - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView  *)entryTextField2{
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
self.entryNameToolBar.hidden =YES; 
self.textBodyToolBar.hidden =NO;
self.textbodyBarButton.style =UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
self.textbodyBarButton.title =@"Terminer la saisie";
[self.entryTextField2 setFrame:CGRectMake(24, 50, 273, 140)];
[self.textBackground setFrame:CGRectMake(0,46,312,140)];
  }

  - (IBAction)textViewDidEndEditing: (UITextView  *)entryTextField2{
      [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
      self.entryNameToolBar.hidden =NO;
      self.textBodyToolBar.hidden =YES;
      [self.entryTextField2 setFrame:CGRectMake(24, 50, 273, 140)];
      [self.textBackground setFrame:CGRectMake(0,46,312,140)];
      self.textbodyBarButton.style =UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
      self.textbodyBarButton.title =@"Corps de texte";  

  }

  - (IBAction)dismisskeyboard{

[self.entryTextField1 resignFirstResponder];
  }

  - (IBAction)dismissKeyboardfromTextView{

[self.entryTextField2 resignFirstResponder];

  }

  - (void)saveContext {

      NSError *error = nil;
      if (self.managedObjectContext != nil) {
          if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erreur" 
        message:@"blabla" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];


        abort();

          } 
      }
  }  


  - (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

      // if there's text in textfield1 and textfield2 and a category has been set 
      if (([self.entryTextField1.text length]!= 0) && ([self.entryTextField2.text length]!= 0) && ([self.catLabel.title length]!= 0)){ 

    [self.entry setValue:self.entryTextField1.text forKey:@"entryname"];
    [self.entry setValue:self.entryTextField2.text forKey:@"textbody"];
    [self.entry setValue:self.catLabel.title forKey:@"category"];

    if (self.isChecked == YES) {
        [self.entry setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]forKey:@"active"];
    }
    else {

        [self.entry setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"active"];
    }

    [self.entry setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"editable"];

    //save
    NSError *error;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    [self saveContext];

    //Return to mainview
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.entry release];
    //self.entry =nil;
}

else {

    if([self.entryTextField1.text length] ==0){

        UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] 
                             initWithTitle:@"Oooops..." 
                             message:@"Your entry has no name" 
                             delegate:nil 
                             cancelButtonTitle: @"ok" 
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
    else {

        if ([self.entryTextField2.text length]==0){

            UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oooops..." message:@"Your list is empty" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];

        }
        else {

            if ([self.catLabel.title length]==0){

                UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oooops..." message:@"You need to choose a category for this list first." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];

                  }
              }

          }
      }
   }


  - (void)setEditing {
  //    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
  }




  #pragma mark -
  #pragma mark Undo support

  - (void)setUpUndoManager {

    if (self.entry.managedObjectContext.undoManager == nil) {

    NSUndoManager *undoMgr = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
    [undoMgr setLevelsOfUndo:1];
    self.entry.managedObjectContext.undoManager = undoMgr;
    [undoMgr release];


    }

    // Register as an observer of the entry's context's undo manager.
    NSUndoManager *entryUndoManager = self.entry.managedObjectContext.undoManager;
NSNotificationCenter *dnc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [dnc addObserver:self selector:@selector(undoManagerDidUndo:) name:NSUndoManagerDidUndoChangeNotification object:entryUndoManager];
    [dnc addObserver:self selector:@selector(undoManagerDidRedo:) name:NSUndoManagerDidRedoChangeNotification object:entryUndoManager];


  }


  - (void)cleanUpUndoManager {

      // Remove self as an observer.
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

      if (self.entry.managedObjectContext.undoManager == undoManager) {
          self.entry.managedObjectContext.undoManager = nil;
          self.undoManager = nil;
      }       
  }


  - (NSUndoManager *)undoManager {
      return self.entry.managedObjectContext.undoManager;
  }


  - (void)undoManagerDidUndo:(NSNotification *)notification {

  }


  - (void)undoManagerDidRedo:(NSNotification *)notification {

  }

  - (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
      return YES;
  }


  - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewDidAppear:animated];
      [self becomeFirstResponder];
  }


  - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
      [self resignFirstResponder];
  }

- (void)viewDidUnload {

// Release any properties that are loaded in viewDidLoad or can be recreated lazily.


self.entryTextField1 =nil;
self.entryTextField2 = nil;
self.catLabel = nil;
self.entryNameToolBar = nil;
self.textBodyToolBar = nil;
self.reviewCheck = nil;
self.textBackground = nil;
self.reviewButton = nil;
self.entry = nil;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
[self cleanUpUndoManager];
self.entry.managedObjectContext.undoManager = nil;


}

  - (void)dealloc {

[entryTextField1 release], entryTextField1 = nil;
[entryTextField2 release], entryTextField2 = nil;
[catLabel release], catLabel = nil;
[entryNameToolBar release], entryNameToolBar = nil;
[textBodyToolBar release], textBodyToolBar = nil;
[reviewCheck release], reviewCheck = nil;
[textBackground release], textBackground = nil;
[reviewButton release], reviewButton = nil;
[self cleanUpUndoManager];
[entry.managedObjectContext.undoManager release],  
     entry.managedObjectContext.undoManager = nil;
[entry release],entry = nil;
[managedObjectContext release];


[super dealloc];
}
```

I'm sorry, this is a long bit of code I know but I'm at a loss. Please help me.

As you guys suggested, I did the following modifications :

I've also changed the viewDidUnload and Dealloc portions of the code which now look like this :

I don't quite understand the release + nil concept nor the difference between calling [self.object release] and [object release] in the dealloc and while calling self.object = nil in viewDidUnload.

Comment: There's too much here for anyone to be able to help you. You will need to be a bit more specific so my first suggestion is that you determine if it is definitely your `EntriesDetailedViewController` that is causing the increase in memory usage. To do that simply add a breakpoint to the `dealloc` method in your `EntriesDetailedViewController` instance and see if it gets called when you pop it from the navigation stack. If not, you know the problem is somewhere inside that controller. Then we can start helping you!

Comment: Here's a small suggestion for your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method: `EntriesDetailedViewController *vc = [[EntriesDetailedViewController alloc] init];
Entry *selectedEntry = (Entry *)[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
vc.entry = selectedEntry;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];}

Comment: @Rog - Hello, I implemented the change you suggested above regarding the vc (which is definitely better in two letters) and yes, the breakpoint is called in the dealloc. See above in the code what the dealloc looks like. I'm currently reading a documentation about how instrument alloc works.

Comment: @Miky cool, if `dealloc` is being called, you can eliminate your `detailsViewController` as part of the problem. The controller's dealloc method would not be called if there were any retained objects within its scope.

Comment: @Rog - What should I do then ? hang myself ? ;-)

Comment: @Miky First thing is probably tidy up the question above, remove the unnecessary parts and update the code where you've made the suggested changes here. Then try and run Instruments with Leaks, and see what happens with your LIVE bytes as you test the different controllers in your app. Hopefully you will find a pattern somewhere, then you can post it here along with the relevant parts of your code so someone can try and help. At the moment we are just making educated guesses. Another simple way of monitoring mem allocation is to run the app in the simulator along with OS X's Activity Monitor.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I will test all that and... Yes you are right, I'll tidy up the code above. Thanks for your tips and advice in the mean time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey hey, you know what guys ? I've just found out !!!!!!!! 
How stupid I am...
If you look carefully into the entriesDetailedViewController.h file, you can see that there's a textbodyBarButton that is declared... Well, it was not released, I had forgotten about that one...

So I'm sorry for making you lose your time.

I've just added :

```
    self.textbodyBarButton = nil;
[textbodyBarButton release];
```

And I'm fine now, when I go back to the rootViewController, all the memory is released.

So if you guys have the same problem one day, it might be as stupid as that. Just check twice what you have declared in your .h file.

Waouh, 3 days spent on that however...

Big up to you all and thanks again for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

You should expect your memory usage to go up every time you allocate a new `EntriesDetailedViewController`. I assume you mean that your memory doesn't go back down when you release it? You're probably not releasing something correctly in `-[EntriesDetailedViewController dealloc]`.

Note that rather than generating a new `EntriesDetailedViewController` every time, it's probably better here to just create one the first time you need it, and just keep re-configuring it with `setEntry:`. You've already set up the ivar to hold the view controller; might as well make use of that.

Comment: Hi, I wish I knew how to do that... ;-(. If that's not asking too much, could you illustrate it with a bit of code please ?

Answer (score 0):

The cause isn't obvious from the code you posted, but Instruments shows you where each allocation took place, so it shouldn't be hard to track it down.

Comment: Your `-viewDidLoad` allocates a bar button item without releasing it: `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(save:)];`.

Comment: You're right -- I missed that. However, I'd suggest releasing it after you assign it to the navigation item. If the item wants to hold onto it, it'll retain it. For all you know, the navigation item could be copying it, and you might be inappropriately releasing its copy. I doubt that really happens, but generally you don't want to be releasing some other object's properties.

Comment: @Caleb - The rightBarButton IS in the dealloc. Isn't it released properly ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yet, it has little impact and my heapshots show the heap is growing by 20 ko each time.

Comment: Not to belabor the point, but do this: `UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init...]; self.navigationItem.rightButtonItem = rightButton; [rightButton release];` Otherwise, you're depending on the assumption that the nav item gives you back the same object that you set. It happens that it does, but it wouldn't if the rightButtonItem property were a specified as 'copy' rather than 'retain', and at that point you'd be releasing the wrong object. That'd be both a leak and an incorrect release.

Comment: Use Build & Analyze to help you find potential leaks. If it doesn't identify any, make sure that you understand what Instruments is telling you. I don't suppose you're looking at "Overall Bytes" in the Allocations tool, are you? That's the total bytes allocated during the life of the program, including those blocks that have been deallocated. Sometimes that confuses people. Mouse over one of the block types in the list and click the -> button to display info for individual allocations. This will show you what method allocated each block.

Comment: @Caleb - Thanks Caleb. I'm here to learn so I don't mind your pointing to my mistakes. I started learning objective C only a few months ago and I'm definitely not a pro, and each step is not without pain, so I will never find the words to say how thankful I am to people like you. Just one thing though, there's a typo here as it is not "self.navigationItem.rightButtonItem" but "self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem". As to the instrument, no, I'm not looking at the overall Bytes but at Heap Growth. I'll follow your advice as regards Build and Analyse. In the meantime, thanks again.

Comment: Oh, by the way guys, Build and Analyse reports No Issues.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this form in dealloc:

`[entryTextField1 release], entryTextField1 = nil;`

you should use this form to set (e.g. in `viewDidUnload`):

`self.entryTextField1 = nil;`

running static analysis should catch a few more issues. fix them.

once all that is corrected, then re-run the app. (i assume that will not be 100% coverage)

also, make sure you use version control. you will find yourself hunting down a lot of issues - until they are all sorted out, you should expect more issues/crashes along the way.

unfortunately, you can't avoid memory issues forever, and it is painful to track some of them down --while learning proper memory  management at the same time (iow, the hard way). good luck!

Comment: Well, I did what you said regarding the entryTextField1 and the others. I will edit the code above to show the changes. I've tried the Static analysis tool but it  doesn't seem to report any pb on the detailedViewController.

Comment: the second point i made (about setters) was not implemented/updated - you must use 'self' to message via the accessor. it is the accessor that is responsible for managing the ivar's reference counting for the object. your undo manager is also over-released (when nil is not returned) in dealloc - do you really need an ivar for it?

Comment: ok, I'll edit the code right away for the viewDidUnload and I'll change the code for the undomanager. Is that correct now ? Oh, by the way, do you happen to know where I could find a good tuto about that ?

Comment: Hi again, just a quick question, actually, I have a rootView controller that pushes the entriesViewConroller which contains the tableView. And when you click on a row, you then go to the entriesDetailedViewController. When you asked me if the dealloc was being called, I said it was, but actually, it is being called only when you go back to the rootViewController, not when you go to the entriesDetailedViewController. Is that normal or not ?